# Laravel exception handler for queue worker

Tags: php, laravel, exception, beanstalkd

I am having a weird issue while throwing the exception inside my beanstalkd job class. When I throw a simple exception (`throw new \Exception();`) outside the job class, it calls the report() method in App\Exceptions\Handler and I can do my tweaks there. But when I throw the exception inside the job class, it does not call the report() method. All the queue implementation is based on laravel documentation(https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues) and works great. What can be the reason for this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it had to be different for queues. If a job fails (throws an exception), you don't want to give the control to the Exception handler – you want to catch the error and mark the job as failed.

Look inside Worker.php (line 294+):

```
protected function raiseExceptionOccurredJobEvent($connection, Job $job, $exception)
{
    if ($this->events) {
        $data = json_decode($job->getRawBody(), true);

        $this->events->fire(new Events\JobExceptionOccurred($connection, $job, $data, $exception));
    }
}
```

See `process()` on lines 201-223 as well.

Laravel will catch the exception but will fire an Event to let you know there has been a problem. If you need to hook into it – just listen for this event.

Comment: Thanks @Denis Mysenko. I agree. Listening to the event seems to be a better idea which makes the code clean and handy.

Comment: i have another Worker.php in my Laravel 5.1. What version do you use?

Comment: In laravel 5.3 I have found this function. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With laravel 5.1 I had the same problem when I was using `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync` when I changed it to `QUEUE_DRIVER=redis` and exception handler started to do it's job, I mean stardted to call the `report()` method.

Be sure you use run start `artisan queue:work redis` with `--daemon`